# Heat retention of parchment paper vs aluminum foil vs oven bag

Tags: baking, equipment, temperature

Let's say a pepper is completely but loosely wrapped in either tin foil, parchment paper, or a Reynold's oven bag. Let's say the oven is maintaining a relatively constant temp.

Which would cook the food faster? Also, which would take faster to get up to the temp matching the oven temperature?

Comment: If you need to cook food fast, you shouldn't be choosing a recipe which involves wrapping it up and placing it in the oven. The whole point of these methods revolves around cooking slowly.

Answer (score 1):

In all 3 cases, we are talking of something with a very high surface to volume ratio, not of bulk materials. Any heat exchange will be affected by the large exposed area and the relative little mass that needs to undergo that heat exchange.

The little differences due to the mass and heat capacity of the 3 materials might be computable but hardly appreciable in a cooking setting. I suspect we are talking of at most, to be generous, a second difference in cooking time.